# Notify module to cleanup before FreeLibrary of Module DLL

Tags: apache, apache-modules

Does Apache Web server notify a module in any way that it is about to unload the module?

On Windows I am looking for a way to do some cleanup inside a Module DLL before the DLL is unloaded  because of the [possibilities of thread deadlock inside `DLLMain()`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070904-00/?p=25283) `DLLMain` handles both process detachment as well as thread detachment and as such you cannot wait for a thread when the process is detached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came upon Apache's `apr_pool_cleanup` and the companion `apr_pool_cleanup_register` procedure which registers a hook into the the cleanup. This will allow you to do some proper cleanup before the DLL is unloaded